# Converting a list of lists and scalars to a list of PyTorch tensors throws warning

Tags: python, pytorch, warnings, tensor

I was converting a list of lists to a PyTorch tensor and got a warning message. The conversion itself isn't difficult. For example:

```
>>> import torch
>>> thing = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3], 2, 3]
>>> thing_tensor = list(map(torch.tensor, thing))
```

I get the warning:

```
home/user1/files/module.py:1: UserWarning: To copy construct from a tensor, it is recommended to use sourceTensor.clone().detach() or sourceTensor.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True), rather than torch.tensor(sourceTensor).
```

and am wondering what the reason may be. Is there any other way to convert the data into a tensor that I'm not aware of? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your warning but failed to do so, using your codes thing_tensor produced a list of tensor without giving me a warning. Could you provide the pytorch version you are using ?

Comment: The code you have does not produce that error - perhaps you were actually running different code? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your warning but failed to do so. However, I could get the same warning by creating if I replaced the lists in `thing` by tensors.

I'll go over why it is better to use `x.clone().detach()` rather than `torch.tensor(x)` to make a copy :

On my version of pytorch using `torch.tensor` will work to create a copy that is no longer related to the computational graph and that does not occupy the same place in memory. However, this behaviour could change in future versions which is why you should use a command that will remain valid. I'll illustrate problems that come with note being detached or occupying the same spot in the memory.

**Not being detached :**

```
x = torch.tensor([0.],requires_grad=True)
y = x.clone()
y[0] = 1
z = 2 * y
z.backward()
print(x, x.grad)
```

```
tensor([0.], requires_grad=True) tensor([0.])
```

As you can see the gradient of x is being updated while the computation is done on y, but changing the value of y won't change the value of x because they don't occupy the same memory space.

**Occupying the same memory space :**

```
x = torch.tensor([0.],requires_grad=True)
y = x.detach().requires_grad_(True)
z = 2 * y
z.backward()
y[0] = 1
print(x, x.grad)
```

```
tensor([1.], requires_grad=True) None
```

In this case, the gradients are not updated but changing the value of y changes the value of x because they occupy the same memory space.

**Best practice :**

As suggested by the warning, the best practice is to both detach and clone the tensor :

```
x = torch.tensor([0.],requires_grad=True)
y = x.clone().detach().requires_grad_(True)
z = 2 * y
z.backward()
y[0] = 1
print(x, x.grad)
```

```
tensor([0.], requires_grad=True) None
```

This ensures that future modifications and computations from `y` won't affect `x`

Answer (score 1):

@StatisticDean has a nice answer, I'll just add one bit specific to what you're doing:

"I was converting a list of lists to a PyTorch tensor" - That is not at all what is happening.  Your example code converts a list of lists of numbers to a list of tensors.  Print out thing_tensor, it should be:

```
[tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), tensor([2, 3]), tensor(2), tensor(3)]
```

This is because map calls torch.tensor on each element of the top-level list, creating separate tensors.  Also, this runs without any errors.

What probably happened is that you first tried `torch.tensor(thing)` to convert the list of lists in one go, and got an error `ValueError: expected sequence of length 5 at dim 1 (got 2)`.  The reason for that is tensors must be rectangular - eg for a 2D tensor, each row/column should be the same size.  You can't actually convert the list of lists you have to a tensor, not without changing the sizes of some of the elements.

An example of converting a list of lists to a single tensor with just one call:

```
torch.tensor([[11,12,13],[21,22,23]])
```

Works fine since each row is size 3, and each column size 2; no map needed.

Answer (score 0):

It works well on my Pytorch environment.
I think the warning you met was due to another reason like as Pytorch version or python version, etc.

[This is my result to run your code without any correction.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hBnl.png)